# Resizing Excel FormulaArray Range to display all data

Tags: c#, excel

I am working with Excel in c#.  I have a problem in that a FormulaArray I'm working with has dynamic dimensions.  I can update the FormulaArray with a new data array but the cell range allocated for it does not automatically shrink/expand to fit the new data size.  Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot.

Comment: Are you using a certain library?

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for the offer of help but I resorted to caching the return array size in my XLL and exposing the cached values via a UDF.

Comment: A MCVE would be XLL function Fred which generates 2 random numbers x,y in {1..10} and returns an XLOPER array of x,y elements.  Excel would be set up to call this function in a FormulaArray of a Range.
I'm using MSVC++ for my XLL and MSVC# with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for my automatically do Excel stuff code.  I'm using Excel VB for the GUI.